# Problem with median and even functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

f(x) is even, so the median will be always 0? Can I assume this?

Assume that a continuous random variable $X$ has a probability density function
$f$ satisfying $f (x) = f (-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $M$ is the median of $X$, then:
What do I choose as a correct answer?

1) $M = 1$.

2) $M = 0$.

3) Nothing can be concluded about $M$.

Comment: what whe know is that: M is the median of even probability density function, So we can assume that 0 will be always the median of this kind o function right?

Answer (score 0):

$0$ is a median since you will have $\mathbb P(X \le 0) \ge \frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X \ge 0) \ge \frac12$

But consider $f(x)=\frac12$ when $-4 \lt x \lt -3$ and $3 \lt x \lt 4$ while $f(x)=0$ otherwise. This will have $-3$ and $3$ also as medians and any values inbetween

Comment: So the number 3 is the answer right?

Comment: It depends on the examiner: (2) is right is the sense that $0$ is always a median of such a distribution, so that sense something can be concluded about the media.  But in another sense the question can be wrong when it talks about *the* median

Comment: Can you help me in the other question ? I will have an exam tomorrow...